# How can I set an interpolated value, as a style property in Angular?

Tags: css, angular

Before creating this question, I've read all the question existing, and none of the answers has fixed my issue.

Well, I'm fetching a data from API, `{{ album.image["3"]["#text"] }}` - is the link to the .png file which I would like to set as background-image of the . Here is the example of my code:

```
 <div class="album-grid">
    <div *ngFor="let album of albums">
      <div class="album"> <--! I want here to set a backgroundImage for each album-->
        <h4>{{ album.name }},</h4>
        <h5>by {{ album.artist.name }}</h5>
        <p>{{ album.image["3"]["#text"] }}</p> <--! this is the link to .png file I'm getting from server -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

here is the solutions I've tried, but none of them helped me:

```
[style.backgroundImage]="album.image['3']['#text']"

[style]="backgroundImage: {{album.image['3']['#text']}"

[ngStyle]="{ 'backgroundImage': album.image['3']['#text'] }"
```

Link to my repo -> https://github.com/paslavskyi9roman/Spotilar

On a picture, you can see a grid of albums, with the album name, artist name, and link to album cover file which need to be a background image
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRjFI.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `url()` part.

Try the following (as seen in your repository)

```
<div class="album" [ngStyle]="{ 'backgroundImage': 'url('+ album.image['3']['#text'] + ')'}">
        <h4>{{ album.name }},</h4>
      </div>
      <h5>by {{ album.artist.name }}</h5>
    </div>
```